# how to get maximum of another column for a grouped column

Tags: sharepoint-server, caml-query, caml

in my SharePoint list I have below columns and meta data:

```
  Doc No       Rev
  Doc-0001     00
  Doc-0001     01
  Doc-0001     02
  Doc-0002     00
  Doc-0002     01
```

Now I want below to result in the view or query, that added another column that show maximum Rev for each Doc No

```
Doc No      Rev                Maximum Rev
Doc-0001     00                      02   
Doc-0001     01                      02
Doc-0001     02                      02
Doc-0002     00                      01
Doc-0002     01                      01
```

I am using SharePoint 2013; I do not know which tools I have to use for solving my problem.
I have read something about CAML in the Net but i do not know how I have to use it for solving my problem and also is it the best tool for this scenario or I have to use other tools.

Regards,
Masoud

Comment: You can refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516073/max-query-using-caml

Comment: Thanks, I would like normal result return and a new column that gets maximum value (Maximum Rev) depend on another column (Doc No), the link you have sent it seems find maximum a column in the list not depend on another column, I am looking for something like sub-query in MS Access, and also more explanation about i can put the code in a calculated column list in SharePoint?